# set_by_lua_block (and alike) always convert the type to string

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have the following:

```
set_by_lua_block $tags {
    local cjson=require("cjson")
    return cjson.encode({language="english"})
}
```

And then in the main app, I log this:

```
logger.info(asString(ngx.var.tags))
logger.info(type(ngx.var.tags)
```

This prints

```
{"language":"english"}
string
```

Why is the variable set to a string and not a table?

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening here:

- You encode the table as JSON with `cjson.encode`, this returns a string
- `ngx.var` can only hold strings, as nginx variables can also be used for non-Lua directives

If you want to carry complex values from one block to another on the same request, [ngx.ctx](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxctx) is what you are looking for.

For example:

```
rewrite_by_lua_block {
   ngx.ctx.tags = {language="english"}
}
...
log_by_lua_block {
   ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "language: ", ngx.ctx.tags.language)
}
```

Note that no JSON conversion is involved here.